# Jenkins class with stage inside of it

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline

I'm having some issues trying to use the stage function into a class
I have 3 files

- My pipeline
- A shared function
- A class

In my shared function I'm wanting to use this class, and in the class, I have my stage, like this:

Shared function:

```
new myClass(text: text).print()
```

And in my class I have this:

```
class myClass implements Serializable {
      String text
      myClass print() {
         stage("Printing message") {
            echo text
         }
      }
}
```

But when I do this I receive an error saying the myClass doesn't have the stage function.
Anyone knows what I can do with this?

Comment: More information about context is needed, but this appears to be a class in a library, and not a global var method. The global var method will automatically import the Jenkins Pipeline stage step method, but a class in a library will not. You would need to import that yourself.

Comment: What is this library that I need to import?